# How to access dictionary valuesinside list in the data frame column

Tags: python, json, dictionary, list-comprehension, google-analytics-api

I have a JSON file from Google Analytics Reporting API  - called `response` that looks like this:

```
{'sessions': [{'sessionId': '1632227669',
   'deviceCategory': 'desktop',
   'platform': 'Windows',
   'dataSource': 'web',
   'activities': [{'activityTime': '2021-09-21T12:45:54.236723Z',
     'source': 'google',
     'medium': 'organic',
     'channelGrouping': 'Organic Search',
     'campaign': '(not set)',
     'keyword': '(not provided)',
     'landingPagePath': '/blog-entry/',
     'activityType': 'GOAL',
     'goals': {'goals': [{'goalName': 'GOAL NAME'}]}}]}]}
```

I am trying to convert it to a table, `activityTime` is a unique identifier, some `activities` contain goals, some pageviews and some events. I have this code to convert it to a table:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(response['sessions'], 
                       record_path=['activities'],
                       meta=['sessionId','deviceCategory','platform']
```

which returns a table but `df['goals.goals']` returns Nan or a list of dictionaries, how can I access the keys inside, specifically how to create a new column called `goalName` and append it to `df`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a non-iterrows way to handle it in bulk, but this works.  It only inserts the new column value when `goals.goals` has a value.

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if type(row[1]['goals.goals']) is list:
        df.loc[row[0],'goalName'] = row[1]['goals.goals'][0]['goalName']
```